# Selecting some part of a string from a column in hive and getting a count

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a column 'Platform' with rows as below.

name3:"string1/string2/string3/s:1.2.1/ABCD/XYZ".

And i have another column name with name 'name2'. My table looks like this

```
' id       |    name2     |   name3
-----------+--------------+---------------------
 1         |      x1      | string1/string2/string3/s:1.2.1/ABCD/XYZ
 2         |      x1      | string1/string2/string3/S:2.2.1/ABCD/XYZ
 3         |      x2      | string5/string4/string3/s:1.1/ABCD/XYZ
 4         |      x3      | string1/string6/string7/m:0.2.2/ABCD/XYZ
 5         |      x2      | string1/string2/string3/S:2.2.0/ABCD/XYZ'
```

I want to get counts of event based on substrings of platform. like

```
'name3     | X1    |   X2 |    X3    |

string4        |       |   1  |          |
string6        |       |      |   1      |'
```

or if i want to get the count based on just 'android' or 'iOS', how can i do that?

```
'name3     | X1    |   X2 |    X3    |

 string4          |       |   1  |          |
 string1      |   2   |   1  |   1      |'
```

The query i am using for counts is below. It is working fine for getting the counts of events but unable to figure out how the get the counts based on substrings.

```
'select name2,
    count(1) AS total
from table1 where name2='x1' OR name2='x2' OR name2='x3'
group by name2;'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: In my opinion this database-design is totally wrong. I would set up a table with a platform(name) column and then do a 1-N relation (1 event-(one or many platforms)). Then it would be easy to do what you want to achieve.

Comment: The table is in the form i mentioned and i cannot change it. Can we do it without changing the design? like can we use any regular expressions?

Comment: What form do you mention?

Comment: The first one with columns id,event and platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would split that string up into a view with actual columns. Something like:

```
create view my_view as select
id,
event,
regexp_extract(platform, '^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$', 1) as os,
regexp_extract(platform, '^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$', 2) as brand,
regexp_extract(platform, '^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$', 3) as model,
regexp_extract(platform, '^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$', 4) as lte,
regexp_extract(platform, '^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$', 5) as abcd,
regexp_extract(platform, '^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$', 6) as user,
regexp_extract(platform, '^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$', 7) as xyz
from my_table;
```

Then querying that view is easier. You could also just have this as an inner-query. This sort of "count-where" query where you want different counts in different columns is a pretty common use. The best way I know of to do it is with the pattern:

```
sum(if( [condition] , 1, 0))
```

So for your examples, it would be:

```
select os,
sum(if(event = 'x1', 1, 0)) as x1,
sum(if(event = 'x2', 1, 0)) as x2,
sum(if(event = 'x3', 1, 0)) as x3
from my_view
group by os;
```

Or:

```
select brand,
sum(if(event = 'x1', 1, 0)) as x1,
sum(if(event = 'x2', 1, 0)) as x2,
sum(if(event = 'x3', 1, 0)) as x3
from my_view
group by brand;
```

And here's the above query, but using that view as an inner query instead of an actual view:

```
select brand,
sum(if(event = 'x1', 1, 0)) as x1,
sum(if(event = 'x2', 1, 0)) as x2,
sum(if(event = 'x3', 1, 0)) as x3
from (
  select
  id,
  event,
  regexp_extract(platform, '^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$', 1) as os,
  regexp_extract(platform, '^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$', 2) as brand,
  regexp_extract(platform, '^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$', 3) as model,
  regexp_extract(platform, '^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$', 4) as lte,
  regexp_extract(platform, '^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$', 5) as abcd,
  regexp_extract(platform, '^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$', 6) as user,
  regexp_extract(platform, '^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$', 7) as xyz
  from my_table
) t
group by brand;
```

Comment: Hi, i think you are right. But i just made a small change in the string. i added a sub string like "sfour:4.2.2". Can you look at the complete string above let me know how the regular expression changes for this. Thanks a lot

Comment: Well, the same regular expression would now just capture the whole string "sfour:4.2.2" as one field. If you want to split it into two fields, e.g. "sfour" and "4.2.2", it would be: `'^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*):(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$'` so then there's eight fields you would need to select out (since there's eight capturing groups) instead of seven.

Comment: Hi joe, on quick question.For the above problem, i have two column names for the same string format as mentioned above. one column name is platform and other platform type. The data in both these columns is similar, with the same string format('string1/string2/string3/s:1.2.1/ABCD/XYZ'). Is there a way to include both these columns in the same query?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...

Query:

```
 select a.platforms, a.event, count(1) as count from 
 (select regexp_extract(platform, '^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$',1) 
 as platforms, event from table1) a group by a.platforms, a.event;
```

Output:

```
platforms       event   count
android         x1      2
android         x2      1    
android         x3      1
ios             x2      1
```